# How to change HTML style in ChartOption with if condition?

Tags: javascript, styles, chart.js

I am using Chart.js to draw graphs in my site. Problem is, that I need to change style of in graph data if value of data is 0.

For e.g. I have array (array1) which have this data:
0; 0; 0.125; 0; 0; 0;

So this would display chat like this:

[image]

Code that generate style is like this:

```
function MoreChartOptions(){} 
        var ChartData = {
        labels : labelsArray,
        datasets : [{
            fillColor : "rgba(52,152,219,1)",
            strokeColor : "rgba(52,152,219,0.5)",
            pointColor : "rgba(52,152,219,1)",
            markerShape :"circle",
            pointStrokeColor : "rgba(255,255,255,1.00)",
            data : array1,
            },
        ]};
ChartOptions= {canvasBackgroundColor:'rgba(255,255,255,1.00)',spaceLeft:12,spaceRight:12,spaceTop:12, ...
```

**My question is:** How to change (if it is possible) ChartOptions style (font size - inGraphDataFontSize:12) if value of chart data is 0?

I have try this, but it is not working:

```
ChartOptions=
{canvasBackgroundColor:'rgba(255,255,255,1.00)', ...
...,
for(a=0;a<array1.length;a++){array1[a] != 0 ? inGraphDataFontSize:12 : inGraphDataFontSize:5}, ...
```

Realy thanks for help.

Comment: The error that debugger shows is this: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (" it underline all ChatOptions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create your chart with your `new Chart(....)` statement you get back a chart object that you can manipulate and refresh (using the update() function).

So for example if you want your 0 value bars to be red you can do something like this :

```
var myBarChart = new Chart(document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d")).Bar(ChartData, ChartOptions);

for (var key in myBarChart.datasets[0].bars) {
    if (myBarChart.datasets[0].bars[key].value == 0) {
        // Change 2nd bar to red (display).
        myBarChart.datasets[0].bars[key].fillColor = "rgba(255,0,0,0.7)";
        myBarChart.datasets[0].bars[key].strokeColor = "rgba(255,0,0,1)";
        // Change 2nd bar to red (highlight setting on mouse over)
        myBarChart.datasets[0].bars[key].highlightFill = "rgba(212,10,10,0.7)";
        myBarChart.datasets[0].bars[key].highlightStroke = "rgba(212,10,10,1)";
    }
}

myBarChart.update();
```

[*You can see what it looks like in a jsfiddle here.*](http://jsfiddle.net/rdtome/mxodebzg/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use scriptable options for this in chart.js v3 like so:

```js
var options = {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [0, 19, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      backgroundColor: ctx => (ctx.raw === 0 ? 'red' : 'blue'),
      minBarLength: 10
    }]
  },
  options: {}
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.6.0/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```